# take elements of a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, elements

I have a list of 400 elements and each element is a list of 3 other elements. how can I take the first element of all of 400 elements?
for instance, how can I take elements a,d and g from the following list?

```
list1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
```

Comment: `First /@ list1` or `list1[[All, 1]]`

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: Try also this: `list1 /. {x_, y_, z_} -> x`. Have fun!

Comment: work wonders! thank you.